# Generating random linear programming problems

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra, two-phase-simplex

I've just finished writing a a linear programming problem solver which uses the simplex method.  Now I would like to start optimizing my solver but before I can do this, I need a way of reliably testing it's performance.

What is a good algorithm for generating random linear programming problems of arbitrary size?  If possible I would also like to be able to control whether a solution exists or not and I would like to ensure that the origin is a vertex on the simplex.

Answer (score 6):

If you want a given vector $v \in {\mathbb R}^n$ as a **solution**:

1. take a random $m \times n$ matrix $A$
2. choose a vector $b \in{\mathbb R}^m$ such that $b \ge A v$.

   You can generate b by taking $b=Av+\delta, \delta_i\ge0$

Then the constraints can be $A x \le b$.
Generically, if $m \ge n$ and $b - Av$ has at least $n$ zero entries, $v$ will be a basic solution.

If you want a problem that is **unbounded**

1. pick vectors $u$ and $v$ with $v \ne 0$.
2. Take a random matrix $A$.
   For each $j$ such that $(Av)_j > 0$, multiply row $j$ of $A$ by
   $-1$, so you get a matrix $A$ with $A v \le 0$.
3. Choose $b$ such that $b \ge A u$.  Then $u + t v$ satisfies the constraints $Ax \le b$ for all $t \ge 0$.
4. Take for the objective any vector $c \in
   {\mathbb R}^n$ such that $c^T v > 0$.

If you want a problem that is **infeasible**, take the dual of an unbounded problem.

Comment: Any suggestions about what distribution to draw your random matrix from?

Comment: It's really up to you.   I'd use independent elements, each with some convenient continuous distribution (maybe uniform on an interval, maybe normal).