# Non-Empty Random Set Construction

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, linear-programming

I am aware any set

$$
\mathbb{S} = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n | A x \leq b\} 
$$

where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{q\times n}$, $q\in \mathbb{R}^q$ is convex, yet there is no guarantee it's also non-empty. Is there any convenient way to construct a nonempty (random!) Polyeder?

Right now, I am building some full rank Matrix $B=e^C$ by using $e^C e^{-C} = I$ is always invertible (hence full rank) and $C=rand(m)$ [MATLAB rand](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) with $m=max(n,q)$ and reducing $B$ to the desired dimenions of $A$. It works, yet using this method one has to check for non-emptiness, solving a Linear Feasibility Problem.

Later on, I'd like to construct some set

$$
\mathbb{Q} = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n | A x \leq b, C x = d\} 
$$

which also needs to be random and non-empty. Thanks for your help. Please be kind, engineers are not mathematicians.

Comment: One way to guarantee that $\Bbb S$ is non-empty is to select $b = \|A\| \cdot \vec 1$, where $\|A\|$ denotes the spectral norm (maximal singular value) of $A$ and $\vec 1$ is the vector of $1$s.  I can't speak to how "random" the resulting polytopes will be though

Comment: [This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.641.4100&rep=rep1&type=pdf) indicates that you can generate a random polytope using the convex hull of some number of points, but I'm not sure how one would go from the convex-hull presentation to the matrix-inequality presentation that you're after.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I guess the row-vectors of some matrix $A$ with $Ax \leq b$ would be the vectors which connect the number of points defining the convex-hull. No idea about $b$ then though.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Link is broken. What's the paper?

Comment: @user76284 Sorry, I don't remember

Comment: This recent survey [Recent Results on Random Polytopes](http://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/rschnei/Vortrag.Perugia.pdf) by Rolf Schneider describes three methods for generating random polytopes in $d$-dimensional Euclidean space, one of which is convex hulls of finitely many points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, inspired by [another math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244142/generating-random-linear-programming-problems), I will present my solution, so this question will not remain unanswered. (In this case, when I say random, I mean any $f_{ij}$ in a matrix F is uniformly distributed in [-a,a] and $F$ is [full rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273061/how-to-randomly-construct-a-square-full-ranked-matrix-with-low-determinant). I believe it works for any distribution).

First of all, I will generate some random $x$ and $C$, then calculate

$$d=Cx$$

This will ensure $Cx=d$ is solvable for some $x$ I have chosen. Then generate some random $A$, and calculate

$$b_{temp} = Ax$$

So far, the chosen $x$ is simply the intersection of the two hyperplanes defined by $Cx=d$ and $Ax=b_{temp}$. By increasing $b_{temp}$, the system recieves degrees of freedom.

$$b = b_{temp} + e$$

where $e_i > 0, \forall i$ and therefore $Ax\leq b$ and $\mathbb{Q} = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n | Ax\leq b, Cx=d\}$ should be non-empty.